# How not to store cache js files to client

Tags: .htaccess

I put this code in my .htaccess file to disable caching for js files but my website still caches js files to client.

```
# DISABLE CACHING
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires 0
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "\.(js)$">
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresActive Off
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        FileETag None
        Header unset ETag
        Header unset Pragma
        Header unset Cache-Control
        Header unset Last-Modified
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Expires "Thu, 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Please include the HTTP response headers for a `.js` file request.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Check the network tab in the browser dev tools and select a `.js` file request to view the HTTP request and response headers for that request. Check the "disable cache" checkbox on the toolbar to ensure you are seeing the response headers as sent from your server. (How are you currently determining that the `.js` files are being cached client-side in the browser?)